# Marsden and Hughes Mathematical Foundations of Elasticity Derivation

Tags: coordinate-systems, elasticity

in the beginning of the book they discuss transformation between coordinate systems and they use this to show that the velocity of a point transforms into that coordinate system;, in terms of the basis vectors of the new coordinate system, the velocity is just the derivative of the transformed motion mapping. There's two things that I am unsure about.

This appears on page 30 of the book.

Firstly, the brackets here and the notation confuse me:
[image]

I assume that this means the unit vectors e<sub>a</sub> are the basis vectors of the new coordinate system, dependent upon the transformation to the new coordinates x<sup>b</sup> but then why does it change to a contravariant object on the next line? The brackets here are incomplete which might help but this makes no sense to me.

[image]

Once again I'm at a loss here but this time I just have no idea how these expressions are equivalent. Perhaps it is due to the change from covariance to contravariance and it's something obvious that I should know, but I usually associate such a change with a metric.

Comment: *** Edit *** 
One of my friends helped me with this and he uses the following logic, which seems completely sound: 
 [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tOd7I.jpg

I wasn't sure if it was just a simple chain rule like this because I had derived the same expression effectively, but I'd appreciate any clarification comments all the same.

Comment: *** Edit Two ***

So I have a more rigorous derivation that I thin k works but I'd like feedback on it. Basically we start with:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/5nsJA.gif

Then we can write, from earlier on the book:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gpxk.gif

And, since we only look at the temporal derivative of phi we can consider it's spatial components fixed with respect to the derivative and so:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/0ReMB.gif

Hence we finally have:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/jdisc.gif

Comment: *** Edit Three *** Sorry, the first image in the above comment should be:   http://i.stack.imgur.com/GUf9h.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, but I was kept quite busy these days.
First, let me note that I find their notation, especially in respect to coordinate systems, a tad confusing too. I will still try my best to comment on these issues.
Concerning your first point - I am quite positive that $ \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi^a \right) e^a$ is a simple mistake and should read $ \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi^a \right) e_a$ - especially as $e_a$ (or $e^a$) remains unchanged in the first step but after the equal sign, they write $e_a$. $e_a (x^b(\phi(X,t)))$ makes sense if you refer to their definition of coordinate systems on page 28 (1.6). As the basis vectors introduced there could be changing throughout space, specifying where they are taken is actually useful (and yes, you are right - this needs three round brackets).
The second confusion has nothing to do with changing from contra- to covariant, thus no need for a metric here. They simply perform a change of basis. Refer to page 26 of their work: $\phi^i_z$ denotes in their notation the components in standard cartesian coordinates which need to be connected to the components $\phi^a$ by $\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial z^i}$.
Did this clear things up a bit?

Comment: Yes, I had actually figured it out but forgot to come back and say it here. This confirms it though; I wasn't 100%  sure.